# Accessing userModel in CakePhp 2.2.3

Tags: cakephp-2.2

I'm in the process of upgrading from Cake 1.3 to the latest Cake 2.

I used to access the user model from the App Component as:

```
$this->Auth->userModel->
```

However, that field is not there anymore.

Is there an alternative?

I also tried

```
App::uses('User', 'Model');
$user = new User();
```

but I get the error

```
Class 'AppModel' not found
```

Any alternative way of accessing the user model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you want to do by accessing the User (or any) model?

If in a Controller you can add the Model with the controller's `$uses` variable:

```
public $uses = array('User');
```

You can also access any Model by "jumping over the Model associations". For example if you're in the `UsersController` and you wish to use the `Costume` model where `User hasMany Costume` and `Costume` is not in the Controller's `$uses` property, you can do:

```
$this->User->Costume->find();
```

The existence of a Model Association is mandatory otherwise it will not work. This is possible since the User model has an internal association to any of it's associated Models.

Since Components wrap Controllers you should be able to do this also there or there should be a reference to the Controller from where you could call: `User->Costume->find();` But in the `Component` you're better of passing data to it from the `Controller` than trying to call a model from it.

Comment: I'm trying to access data from a model associated to the User Model, just as in your example you try to access User->Costume->find(). However, this is a method on AppController, so I can't guarantee I'm currently on UsersController so User model is not necessarily bound to the controller.

Comment: The User model will always be bounded to the UsersController. If you're trying to access a method in the AppController then it will also be available in the Users model since it `extends` the AppController, so: `$this->User->methodName()` will work. In the `Component` you're better of passing data to it from the `Controller` than trying to call a model from it.

Comment: Ok, Now I understand. The solution is using "public $uses" on app controller. Thanks

Comment: No, that will bind the model you include in `AppController's` `$uses` will be binded to Every controller in your application. You could bind it only to the controller you desire to use it it. As I already explained there is also another method where if you have a `Model1 to Model2` association and you already have `Model1` included in `Controller1` you could call `Model2` through `Model1`:
`$this->Model1->Model2>find();`.

Comment: But I want to access the User model from every controller.

Comment: Well just bind it to those Controllers that you need it in. You could also bind in to `AppController` but I don't recommend that since I doubt that you'd really have to use it in every Controller. 
You don't always have to get the data from the DB. If you have some parts of the User Profile that you want to access they maybe already in the Session.